# Can't bind to 'value' since it isn't a known property of 'my-series-details-tooltip' in kendo UI Angular 2

Tags: angular, charts, kendo-ui

I have a create a chart.I am trying to add x and y value in tooltip. Could someone please help how to add field and categoryfield value in tooltip. I have 3 area charts in my chart.

```
<kendo-chart *ngIf="chartData != null">
  <kendo-chart-tooltip [visible]="true" format="{0:c2}" background="white" color="black">
    <template kendoSeriesTooltipTemplate>
      <my-series-details-tooltip [value]="[Balance,Age]"></my-series-details-tooltip>
    </template>
  </kendo-chart-tooltip>
  <kendo-chart-axis-defaults [majorGridLines]="{ visible : false}">
  </kendo-chart-axis-defaults>
  <kendo-chart-y-axis>
    <kendo-chart-value-axis>
      <kendo-chart-value-axis-item>
        <kendo-chart-value-axis-item-labels format="{0:c0}">
        </kendo-chart-value-axis-item-labels>
      </kendo-chart-value-axis-item>
    </kendo-chart-value-axis>
    <kendo-chart-value-axis-item-crosshair></kendo-chart-value-axis-item-crosshair>
  </kendo-chart-y-axis>
  <kendo-chart-category-axis>
    <kendo-chart-category-axis-item>
      <kendo-chart-value-axis-item-labels [step]="xAxisStep">
      </kendo-chart-value-axis-item-labels>
    </kendo-chart-category-axis-item>
  </kendo-chart-category-axis>
  <kendo-chart-series>
    <kendo-chart-series-item type="area" [name]="'high'" [data]="chartData.high" field="Balance" categoryField="Age">
    </kendo-chart-series-item>
    <kendo-chart-series-item type="area" [name]="'medium'" [data]="chartData.medium" field="Balance" categoryField="Age">
    </kendo-chart-series-item>
    <kendo-chart-series-item type="area" [name]="'low'" [data]="chartData.low" field="Balance" categoryField="Age" color="white" opacity="1">
      <kendo-chart-series-item-markers background="#000">
      </kendo-chart-series-item-markers>
    </kendo-chart-series-item>
  </kendo-chart-series>
  <kendo-chart-legend [visible]="true"></kendo-chart-legend>
</kendo-chart>
```

I got the following error for the tooltip in Kendo Ui for Angular 2.

Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'value' since it isn't a known property of 'my-series-details-tooltip'.
1. If 'my-series-details-tooltip' is an Angular component and it has 'value' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'my-series-details-tooltip' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
 ("emplate kendoSeriesTooltipTemplate>
                                    ][value]="[Balance,Age]">
                                
If i remove the tooltip template ,the chart looks like this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18165.png)

Comment: could you please post code containing `'my-series-details-tooltip` your component ?

Comment: I was trying to use the category and field category value from series item.

Comment: please post more code related to your error or some plunker where your full code exist

Comment: Most of the times i've seen that message it's related to a missing module or component not being imported correctly into your modules.

Comment: I am new to Kendo UI for Angular 2.Could you please share how to call the x and y values in tooltip.